# Пунктуация в предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите, пожалуйста, расставить знаки препинания!

Рассказывать для чего клиенты стараются пользоваться услугами высокого качества не требуется это очевидно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможна двоякая пунктуация. Зависит от смысла, который вкладывает автор.

Рассказывать, для чего клиенты стараются пользоваться услугами высокого качества, не требуется  - это очевидно.(вывод)

Рассказывать, для чего клиенты стараются пользоваться услугами высокого качества, не требуется :(почему?) это очевидно.(причина)

Я бы тире поставила, перед ЭТО всегда хочется поставить тире.

Comment: Благодарю! Хорошо объяснили